# Why even bother with a UV section?

Tags: texturing, uv

In blender render I'm playing around with textures on materials and I notice there is always this "Mapping" section. There is one important feature of this which is being able to change between global and UV and local and etc. So, with my mesh UV-unwrapped, everything else UV-related works perfectly fine, but I want to modify or offset the display of the texture with the UV map using those alleged settings.

However, after hundreds of projects, literally, I find that changing the size and offset of the UV map in that section literally never, ever, has any microscopic effect in any capacity. What!????? What's the point of even having it then? It literally does nothing, I'm not joking, absolutely nothing.

Comment: please show your nodes organization, maybe also share a file with an example

Comment: For reference, start from the default file in blender render. Then make a basic material with a texture like a cloud texture and unwrap it. That's it. That's literally all there is to it. I don't do anything that might disable the mapping settings, but after starting from scratch 100s of times, I find that those settings still literally do nothing every single time.

Comment: So I guess you're talking about the UV Editor... where are those Global/Local/UV/... you're talking about? Can you please show a screenshot? It will make things easier...

Comment: No the UV editor is fine. As I said, it is the "mapping" section of the materials->texture section of a mesh, in the info panel. It's where you set how the texture is mapped where the global/local/uv settings are. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/properties/mapping.html

Comment: I personally never work the materials in the Properties panel, always in the Node Editor, so could you please tell which node you're talking about? Is it the Mapping one? Texture Coordinate?

Comment: I don't use the node editor very often so I can't exactly tell you. If you're in blender render, and you make a material and a texture, then in the texture panel, there is a section called "mapping" with the image I linked to.

Comment: ok I don't know enough about Blender Render, I hope someone will help